# MySQL: Group Records By Date

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table `order` as following:

```
o_id | o_uid | o_date
1    | 5     | June 10, 2015
2    | 1     | June 10, 2015
3    | 8     | June 10, 2015
5    | 15    | June 11, 2015
6    | 11    | June 11, 2015
7    | 16    | June 12, 2015
8    | 19    | June 12, 2015
```

I tried running the following query:

```
SELECT o_id, o_uid FROM order GROUP BY o_date
```

I thought it will give me result as follows:

```
[
    "June 10, 2015" => [
        [
            "o_id" => 1
            "o_uid" => 5
        ],
        [
            "o_id" => 2
            "o_uid" => 1
        ],
        [
            "o_id" => 3
            "o_uid" => 8
        ]
    ],
    "June 11, 2015" => [
        [
            "o_id" => 4
            "o_uid" => 15
        ],
        [
            "o_id" => 5
            "o_uid" => 11
        ]
    ],
    ...
]
```

The query does not provide results as expected. I can use PHP to get the required results but why not use MySQL if you can and finish things off in a line. The `GROUP BY` Clause is quite confusing. Is there any other clause which can group records by date?

The result I get:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ba44/3)

Comment: If you would store dates in mysql's date format you could easily group by them, even specifieng the day or month to group by. You should consider doing this

Comment: Define "not as expected". What are you getting instead?

Comment: @michael You mean storing NOW() and using DATE(created_at)?

Comment: @Marvin Let me make a fiddle :P

Comment: @RexOverflow can you check answer ?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com Let me check it :D Thanks for being fast.

Comment: @Marvin Updated my question. I haven't tried that query in real table but I have been using SQLFiddle for a time, it works fine.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I think the issue is that you are expecting a hierarchically structured result, which is not what SQL is made for. Maybe there is a way of achieving the desired output, but at least not that I knew of. This looks more like a possible output of a NoSQL database to me.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
SELECT o_id, GROUP_CONCAT(o_id),GROUP_CONCAT(o_uid),o_date FROM `order`  
GROUP BY o_date
```

And then separate comma separated list using php/do manipulation accordingly.

Output : Formatter output from sqlfiddle.

```
o_id    GROUP_CONCAT(o_id)  GROUP_CONCAT(o_uid) o_date
1          1,2,3            5,1,8               June 10, 2015
4          4,5              15,11               June 11, 2015
6          6,7              16,19               June 12, 2015
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ba44/12/0)**